# How can i add a scrollView to a blank Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjqL4.png)   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3M45.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewu3O.png)
So i'm working on on a project and i created a blank Fragment, But now i need to add a scroll view.

So i add a scroll view to the fragment_layout, but i do not know where to implement the code i used for the scroll view. Because every time i try and place this code in the fragment activity the activity crashes when i run it.

**SCROLL VIEW CODE**

```
 TextView mMessageWindow = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.messageWindow);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new 
StringBuilder();
        String someMessage = "" ;
        stringBuilder.append(someMessage);

mMessageWindow.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: bind scrollview in onCretetView() which you setLayout